# React Hooks: how to discard async results when launched from normal event handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand the new React hooks API (I'm using `React 16.8.x` at the moment).

I've found the `useEffect()` hook makes it very easy to discard the results of a server call when the user does something that causes a component to no longer be displayed, as per **(A)**:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  let mounted = true;
  setInvocation("processing");
  MuiServiceApi.instance.
    invokeProcessingMethod(details.endpoint, parsedPayload).
    then(result=> mounted && setInvocation(result)).
    catch(e=> setInvocation({message: "while updating DB", problem: e}));
  return ()=>{mounted = false};
}, []);
```

But how do I achieve similar behaviour when I do a call from a normal form event, as per **(B)**:

```
<form onSubmit={()=>{
  setInvocation("processing");
  MuiServiceApi.instance.
    invokeProcessingMethod(details.endpoint, parsedPayload).
    then(result=> setInvocation(result)).
    catch(e=> setInvocation({message: "while updating DB", problem: e}));
}}>
```

If the user dismisses the component while it's doing the invocation when it's first displayed (i.e. the **(A)** logic), then the result will be discarded cleanly.

If the user dismisses the component while processing, after having clicked the actual submit button (**(B)** logic), there will be a console warning like:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

This isn't really a big deal - in fact, under the pre-hooks `class` API, I never bothered discarding results for unmounted components because it was too much hassle.

But the point of this exercise was to learn about the `Hooks` API, so I'd like to know how I could do this for the `onSubmit` handler.

I tried defining `mounted` with `useState()`, but I can't see how it would work, as per:

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
  setMounted(true);
  setInvocation("processing");
  MuiServiceApi.instance.
    invokeProcessingMethod(details.endpoint, parsedPayload).
    then(result=> {
      if( mounted ){
        console.log("result used");
        setInvocation(result);
      }
      else {
        console.log("result ignored because dismounted");
      }
    }).
    catch(e=> setInvocation({message: "while updating DB", problem: e}));
  return ()=>{
    console.log("dismounted");
    setMounted(false)
  };
}, []);
```

I realise now in hindsight it can't work because because the `mounted` value of `false` is captured by the closure; so the `then` handler won't ever see `mounted == true`.

Is this where "reducers" or "callbacks" are supposed to be used?  The documentation gets pretty vague past the "basic" hooks, so I'm not sure if that's how I'm supposed to make this work.

To restate the question: How should the component below be refactored such that the `then()` handler inside the `form` `onSubmit` will not result in a warning about updating state if the component has already been unmounted?

---

Full component below (in `Typescript`)

```
function InvokeEndpoint(props:{}){
  const [details, setDetails] = React.useState(
    {endpoint: "testPayload", payload: '{"log":["help"]}'} );
  const [invocation, setInvocation] = React.useState
    <"init"|"processing"|ErrorInfo|ProcessingLogV1>("init");

  let isValidEndpoint = !!details.endpoint;
  let isValidPayload = true;
  let payloadErrorText = "";
  let parsedPayload = {};
  try {
    parsedPayload = JSON.parse(details.payload);
  }
  catch( e ) {
    isValidPayload = false;
    payloadErrorText = e.toString();
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    let mounted = true;
    setInvocation("processing");
    MuiServiceApi.instance.
      invokeProcessingMethod(details.endpoint, parsedPayload).
      then(result=> mounted && setInvocation(result)).
      catch(e=> setInvocation({message: "while updating DB", problem: e}));
    return ()=>{mounted = false};
  }, []);

  const isProcessing = invocation == "processing";
  let result = undefined;
  if( invocation != "init" && invocation != "processing" ){
    if( isErrorInfo(invocation) ){
      result = <MuiCompactErrorPanel error={invocation}/>
    }
    else {
      result = <ul>{
        invocation.log.map((it,index)=> <li key={index}>{it}</li>)
      }</ul>
    }
  }

  return <Card><CardContent> <form onSubmit={()=>{
    setInvocation("processing");
    MuiServiceApi.instance.
      invokeProcessingMethod(details.endpoint, parsedPayload).
      then(result=> {
        console.log("resulted", result);
        setInvocation(result);
      }).
      catch(e=> {
        console.log("errored");
        setInvocation({message: "while updating DB", problem: e});
      } );
  }}>
    <Typography variant={"h5"}>Invoke endpoint</Typography>
    <TextField id="endpointInput" label="Endpoint"
      margin="normal" variant="outlined" autoComplete="on" fullWidth={true}
      inputProps={{autoCapitalize:"none"}}
      value={details.endpoint}
      onChange={( event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> )=>{
        setDetails({...details, endpoint: event.currentTarget.value});
      }}
      disabled={isProcessing}
      error={!isValidEndpoint}
    />
    <TextField id="payloadInput" label="Payload"
      margin="normal" variant="outlined" autoComplete="on" fullWidth={true}
      inputProps={{autoCapitalize:"none"}}
      multiline={true}
      value={details.payload}
      onChange={( event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> )=>{
        setDetails({...details, payload: event.currentTarget.value});
      }}
      disabled={isProcessing}
      error={!isValidPayload}
      helperText={payloadErrorText}
    />
    <PrimaryButton type="submit" color="primary"
      disabled={isProcessing || !isValidPayload || !isValidEndpoint}
    >
      <ButtonLabel isLoading={isProcessing}>Invoke</ButtonLabel>
    </PrimaryButton>
    { result }
  </form> </CardContent></Card>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to change `mounted` from a variable to a ref via the React [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) API.

Declare the ref with  `const mounted = React.useRef(false)`, then use `mounted.current` everwhere the previous code was using the variable.

Always accessing the `Ref` value through `current` means the effects and event handlers of the component are all binding to the single "current" value pointed at by the `Ref`, rather than a copy of the what the variable was when the component was rendered.